# Insert or Update into Mongo using mongoose and modify inner elements while updating

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Assume there's a collection with documents where `field_1` is unique

```
[
    {
       field_1: 'abc',
       field_2: 0,
       field_3: []
    }
]
```

I want to add another document, but then `field_1` is the same `'abc'`. In which case I want to increment `field_2`, and append element into `field_3` while updating. And if `field_1` is different, create another document.

What is the best way to approach such queries? My first thought was to search, and then insert if no documents are found, or is there a better way? The problem with this approach is, if I'm inserting multiple documents at once, I can't use 'search and, if no doc found, insert' approach effectively.

Comment: What is the usecase for all this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mongoose now supports this natively with findOneAndUpdate (calls MongoDB findAndModify).

The upsert = true option creates the object if it doesn't exist. defaults to false.

```
MyModel.findOneAndUpdate(
    {foo: 'bar'}, // find a document with that filter
    modelDoc, // document to insert when nothing was found
    {upsert: true, new: true, runValidators: true}, // options
    function (err, doc) { // callback
        if (err) {
            // handle error
        } else {
            // handle document
        }
    }
);
```

Comment: This doesn't address multiple documents getting updated or upserted.

Comment: based on the filter, if criteria is met then it is updated otherwise a new doc is created for a single document. If it is for multiple document you can use findAndModify

Comment: Documentation for [findAndModify](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.findAndModify/)

Comment: What I thought of was,
MyModel.findOneAndUpdate(
    {foo: {$in:bars}}, // find a document with that filter
    modelDoc, // document to insert when nothing was found
    {upsert: true, new: true, runValidators: true}, // options
    function (err, doc) { // callback
        if (err) {
            // handle error
        } else {
            // handle document
        }
    }
);

The problem with this -> it doesn't upsert multiple docs. Just one. and using $in-> doesn't include the queried field. 
How would you suggest using findAndModify?

Comment: In its documentation it is given you could update multiply document, that should do it

Answer (score 1):

If the uniqueness of `field_1` is enforced by unique index, you can use a kind of optimistic locking.

First you try to update:

```
db.collection.update(
    {
       field_1: 'abc'
    },
    {
       $inc: {field_2: 1},
       $push: {field_3: 'abc'},
    }
);
```

and check result of the operation - if 1 document updated, no more actions required. Otherwise, it's the first document with field_1 == 'abc', so you try to insert it:

```
db.collection.insert(
    {
       field_1: 'abc',
       field_2: 0,
       field_3: []
    }
);
```

and catch the error. If there is no error, no more actions required. Otherwise there was a concurrent insert, so you need to repeat the update query once more.

Comment: How would you do the same when using field_1:{$in:['abc','def','ghi','jkl'] }, So assuming 'ghi' and 'jkl' isn't there, I would require to insert for def and ghi. If a certain number of documents were updated, how do you figure out which document was updated, and which weren't so that I can insert in batches, the remaining 'ghi' and 'jkl'

Comment: Sorry, I didn't get it. Where `field_1:{$in:['abc','def','ghi','jkl'] },` came from? As of your original question `field_1` is the unique identifier of the document, so the only condition in update query is to match this string exactly. If you have 4 documents you do them one by one.

Comment: Up to you really. A for loop is an option, yes. I didn't get the callback part. If you are asking how callbacks work in general, it's way too broad. If you have some particular problems with callbacks, please post a question with clear problem statement.