# Update or create multiple documents in a collection using Mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Assume that the document contains the following.

```
[{
    field1 (index): 'abc',
    field2: 1 },{
    field1 (index): 'def',
    field2: 2 
}]
```

And I want to add or update

```
array_1 = ['abc','def','ghi','jkl']
```

by checking `field1`, and for the first two elements of the array increment `field2`, and the next two elements, create a document

```
[{
    field1 (index): 'ghi',
    field2: 0 },{
    field1 (index): 'jkl',
    field2: 0 
}]
```

Approach I took with the help of [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48401972/insert-or-update-into-mongo-using-mongoose-and-modify-inner-elements-while-updat/48403940?noredirect=1#comment83833958_48403940):

```
Collection.findAndModify(
    { "field1": { $in: array_1 } },
    [['field1', 'ascending']],
    { "$inc": { "field2": 1 } },
    { new: true, upsert: true }, 
    function (err, tags) {
        callback(err, question);
    }
);
```

But this creates 2 problems

1. It creates only one document
2. `field1` is missing from the document that is created.

I tried something similar with update function but that behaved the same way too.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Insert or Update into Mongo using mongoose and modify inner elements while updating](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48401972/insert-or-update-into-mongo-using-mongoose-and-modify-inner-elements-while-updat)

Comment: Doesn't address multiple update/create.