# Push if not present or update a nested array mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have model like this

```
{
  "array1": [
    {
      "_id": "12",
      "array2": [
        {
          "_id": "123",
          "answeredBy": []
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

If I have id in array1, push the document into array2 or create new document in array1.

Eg:

If I give have new object

```
{
  "array1": [
    {
      "_id": "123",
      "array2": [
        {
          "_id": "123",
          "answeredBy": [],
        },
        {
          "_id": "456",
          "answeredBy": []
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

else if give _id of array1 as other than 123 i.e., non existing i.e., 657

The result should be:

```
{
  "array1": [
    {
      "_id": "123",
      "array2": [
        {
          "_id": "123",
          "answeredBy": [],
        }
      ]
    }, 
    {
      "_id": "657",
      "array2": [
        {
          "_id": "456",
          "answeredBy": [],
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: [Upsert](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48401972/insert-or-update-into-mongo-using-mongoose-and-modify-inner-elements-while-updat/48402159#48402159) it has the template to update and insert if not present

Comment: In the above link using upsert it is directly updating the field if it matches and giving error if not match. But what I need is to push into the nested array if already present or create new object of in the outer array

Comment: @Veeram. It would be helpful if get a query